# What are some Alternatives to Winamp Visualizations?

Tags: audio, winamp, visualization

I've been using Winamp to display visuals for a production, but I would rather use a dedicated visualization software, as I'm dealing with live audio. Are there any good visualization software that work much like Winamp's visualizations and go with the music?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The Geiss Winamp vis plugin (by the same guy who wrote MilkDrop), has a [screensaver version](http://www.geisswerks.com/geiss/) available that reacts to any audio being played.
- [PlasmaVis](http://www.plasmavis.com) comes as a Windows Media Player vis plugin, a screensaver and stand-alone visualizer.
- [SoundSpectrum](http://www.soundspectrum.com) has a bunch of music visualizers that are highly recommended.
- [VSX (VisXtreme/Visualization Xtreme)](http://visuals.free.vovoid.com) and [VSXu/VSX Ultra](http://www.vsxu.com/products/player) are great as well.
- You can also check out this [list of music visualization software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Music_visualization#List_of_music_visualization_software) on Wikipedia for more.

Comment: I'm looking for the ability to do more professional style things, not so much a screensaver. This will be displayed for an audience going with live music from bands.

Comment: Leave the first one out then, it was just an additional recommendation for home (i.e. non-pro) use. :) Check out SoundSpectrum and VSX/VSXu.

Comment: The best alternative for Linux-computers is definitely [ProjectM](http://projectm.sourceforge.net/). It's all the MilkDrop-visualizers that you might know from WinAmp, but it just works on the sound-output of your machine. (It also is the successor to Geiss, and ProjectM is technically a new re-implementation of MilkDrop)

Answer (score 0):

Soundspectrum has the best visualizations ever, particularly "G-Force", "Aeon" and "WhiteCap". Aeon is slower but the most sophisticated and in 3D. They have two others, "SoftSkies" and "Winter Wonders", but I find these much less interesting.
You can download them for free, but you will have just a basic viz constantly interrupted by the word "Soundspectrum". Upgrading is a must, the cheapest upgrade is $20 each for a year, the top upgrade is $30. This includes constant updates, "standalone" (the viz works without music) and a screensaver.
You can keep and use the viz's after a year, but then the updates will stop.

These visualizations are extremely sophisticated and adjustable, quite a level above Milkdrop and all the Geiss viz's. They work on many media players, when downloading them (from the site itself is best), check on the drop down list all the media players you want to use them with.

WhiteCap can be embedded in most Classic Winamp skins, even the "old" skins, which I think is a nice plus.

Highly recommended, but don't bother if you aren't prepared to buy the top version.

Comment: Are you associated with the product in anyway? As in do you work for the company or something?

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old question, but some days I wanted to know what alternatives I had. So, I found "projectm" (https://github.com/projectM-visualizer/projectm) in my opinion the best current open source alternative to winamp and cross platform visualizations.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1190803)